# What is the inner/esoteric meaning of the this Rig Vedic verse?

Tags: rig-veda

Rig Veda [10.72.2](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10072.htm) says as follows:

> बरह्मणस पतिरेता सं कर्मार इवाधमत | देवानाम्पूर्व्ये युगे.असतः सदजायत
> ||
>
> These Brahmaṇaspati produced with blast and smelting, like a Smith,
> Existence, in an earlier age of Gods, from Non-existence sprang.

Can anyone throw light on the inner/esoteric meaning of this mantra?